# Regex number starting with 0 or allow nothing at all

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to create a regex that allows typing in the following input into a html input:

- it must start with 0
- input may be empty, user may delete characters

`^[^1-9]{0,1}[0-9\\s-\\/]*$`

With the following regex I cannot delete the 0...

`^0[0-9\\s-\\/]*$"`

Comment: You can check if the user has entered something in textbox. If yes, then only apply `regex`. `if (value.length) { /regex/.test(value); }`

Comment: Can you give a little more context?  What's the javascript you are you preventing the input if the regex is met?  That could have an impact on any reasonable answers.

Comment: using angular `ngPatternRestrict` http://alphagit.github.io/ng-pattern-restrict/ to restrict user input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a non-capturing group `(?:...)` around everything between `^` and `$`, and use the `?` operator on it (allow zero or one):

```
^(?:0[0-9\\s-\\/]*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:0[0-9 \\/-]*|)$
```

You can use this instead.See demo.This will allow `empty` as well as strings starting from `0`.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/18